# Stopping jQuery setInterval based on click event

Tags: jquery, setinterval, jquery-events

There is a paragraph that I need to click on but I don't now when it appears on the page, so I'm using jQuery `setInterval` to repeat the click every 500 ms:

```
 setInterval(function() {

   $('p').trigger('click') ;

 },500)
```

This works for me but now it keeps on clicking. Is there any way of 'listening' to the click event and then stop it once the element has been clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may help you,

```
var test_interval = setInterval(function() {
    if($('p:visible').length > 0) {
        $('p').trigger('click') ;
        clearInterval(test_interval);
    }
},500)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {

   $('p').trigger('click') ;

 },500)
```

on click event :

```
clearInterval(interval);
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd set a boolean to check if the button has been click, if so then stop the interval.

```
var stopInterval = false;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if(!stopInterval) {
     $('p').trigger('click') ;
     stopInterval = true;
  } else {
     clearInterval(interval);
  }
},500)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JmG5n/